# Find tuples of points from multiple sets

Tags: computational-geometry, clustering

Given *n* sets of points in general position in dimension 2 (*n* typically small, 2-6), can one find tuples of points, one from each of the sets, which are close in some sense (the closest, mutual distances less than some threshold)?  I'd be interested even in the usual name for this problem.

Comment: You're stating this as an optimization problem. What is your objective function?

Comment: I guess, given _n_ points, take _e_ to be the maximal distance of those points to their centroid.  Ideally I'd like all such n-tuples with _e_ less than some threshold, with no points repeated, and with the sum of _e_ minimal.  That sounds infeasible to me, I'd be happy with something feasible which heads in that direction.

Comment: If you were willing to take the centroid not of your $n$ chosen points, but of the entire data sets, then the problem becomes east: Pick the one point in each set that is closest to the centroid.

Comment: Unfortunately, that wouldn't map to the underlying problem I'm trying to address -- I have _n_ instruments observing a region, with observations from each at different positions; I want to create "composite positions" close to one from each.

Comment: @jjg: Do you wish to find one such tuple or several? If you could draw a picture depicting what you're looking for 2 and perhaps 3 sets of points that would be useful.